# Is the Dadda multiplier faster than the Wallace adder?

Tags: multiplier, computer-arithmetic

If I understand it correctly, the Dadda multiplier adds the partial products in a similar way compared to the Wallace multiplier, but it doesn't reduce the partial product terms as much in its tree and subsequently you may end up with having to do a larger addition at the end. I think I can see why this would lead to less gates for a Dadda adder, but I've heard it's also generally faster than a Wallace multiplier. I was wondering why is this the case? Is it because we allow a larger adder at the end which could be faster depending on the adder used?

Comment: en.wikipedia's entry on "Dadda multipliers" has a hyperlink to a paper by Townsend, Whitney J.; Swartzlander, Jr., Earl E.; Abraham, Jacob A. arguing both [Dadda and Wallace reduction](https://ieeemilestones.ethw.org/w/images/d/db/A_comparison_of_Dadda_and_Wallace_multiplier_delays.pdf). I think the time model, well, basic.

Comment: (Downvoters please comment what in particular makes a post *not useful*.)

Comment: W.r.t. ``but I've heard it's also generally faster than a Wallace multiplier``, the question could be improved by editing to include a citation to support that.